# send value from php to jquery function

Tags: php, jquery

I'm creating an employee scheduler application. I want to create a button to change the calendar view to next or previous month view. But the problem is, when I click the button, the calendar changed, but the employee which has been selected to be viewed on calendar is going back to default.

I have this button in my php file:

```
    <input type="submit" id="month-next" value="Next Month">
```

and I have created jquery for my button:

```
    $('input#month-next').click(function(id){

        if(month==12){
                ++year;
                month=0;
            }
            ++month;

        $('div#month-data').load('scheduler/ajax/calendar.php?month='+month+'&year='+year+'&empid='+id);
    });
```

so, how can I pass a my 'empid' value to my jquery function from the php page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your jquery in same php page you can use

```
$('input#month-next').click(function(){
   var id = '<?php echo $empid ?>';

   //your remaining code
});
```

If your jquery at another place you need to pass as parameter in function call:

```
<input type="button" id="month-next" value="Next Month" onclick="monthNext('<?php echo $empid; ?>');" >
```

Use a function instead of click event as above:

```
function monthNext(id)
{
      if(month==12)
      {
            ++year;
            month=0;
      }
      ++month;

      $('div#month-data').load('scheduler/ajax/calendar.php?month='+month+'&year='+year+'&empid='+id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `button` instead of input `type=submit` because submit will reload page.

Comment: but, how can I send the 'empid' value to the function?

Comment: Onclick event on created button and then u can send into a function object `this`. Later use `.attr('id')` and you will get id

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

With HTML 5 you can use data attributes.

```
<input type="submit" id="month-next" value="Next Month" data-empid="5">
```

JS:

```
$('input#month-next').click(function(){
  id = $(this).data("empid");
  // rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a hidden field where you shore the employee id and after click on the button get that hidden field value like this

```
$('#button').click(function(){
  emp_id = $('#emp_id').val();
  // rest of your code
}
```